# My dog has congestive heart failure and I am considering feeding him bone broth. Is this a bad idea?

Tags: dogs, diet, heart-health

The vet warned me about giving him too much sodium. Per cup the bone broth I am considering has 95mg of sodium.

Comment: Did you ask the vet?

Comment: DId the vet tell you how much was to much?  How much sodium is in his daily food?

Comment: How much is a "cup"? Can you give us the sodium content per 100ml?

Comment: @YElm a cup is 250ml if OP is using a British standard measuring cup